# Ruby/Rails: Merge result of map

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, ruby-on-rails-4, ruby-2.0

I have `@products` collection and I want to merge `image_ids` to single array. Here is the output of `@products.map(&:image_ids)`:

```
@products.map(&:image_ids)
=> [[1654, 1655, 1656],
 [1649, 1650, 1652, 1653],
 [1625],
 [1624],
 [1623],
 [1622],
 [1621],
 [1620],
 [1619],
 [1618]]
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Do as below using [`flat_map`](http://ruby-doc.org/core-2.1.0/Enumerable.html#method-i-flat_map) :

```
@products.flat_map(&:image_ids)
```

Comment: Is there a question you don't answer? :-P +1

Comment: @Abdo Humm.. Lots of... I never participate any Rails question.. as I am baby to rails.. :-)

Comment: @Zeck .. How are you? :)